# How to fetch data from different servers and bring it to one location

Tags: java, server, kubernetes, cloud

I want to fetch the data from different containers where n all my application is deployed and bring it to one location in Java.My data base is different for each container(server)
Is there any API in java that can I use??or any other centralized way through servers??

Please help me in this.Thanks!!

Comment: try feignClient of spring cloud

Comment: To get more reasonable advice, please update the question with some more info - what are the problem you are trying to solve, why in this way, what is the data  - size, throughput, ...